# undefined method [] for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in ruby... Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Here's my code:

```
begin
     items = CSV.read('somefile.csv')
     linesAmount = CSV.readlines('somefile.csv').size
     counter = 1
     while linesAmount >= counter do
       fullrow = items[counter]
       firstitem = fullrow[0] #This is the line that my code doesn't like.
       puts firstitem
       counter = counter + 1

     end


end
```

For some ruby doesn't like that one line, where I have firstitem = fullrow[0]. It throws me the undefined method [] error. BUT, in the console, I can still see it printing the firstitem... So it still prints it, but yet throws an error? What's going on?

However, if I take the first three lines in the while loop OUTSIDE of the while loop, and comment out everything in the loop other than the counter line, then I don't get any error. So if that firstitem line appears outside the while loop, the code thinks it's all fine.

Edit: I know that the arrays start from 0, but I specifically wanted counter to not care about the very first line. I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Edit2: Thank you everyone, I solved it by adding -1 after linesAmount, and it works!

Comment: Arrays in ruby are zero-based. On `counter == linesAmount` it’s the `linesAmount+1` line and `items[counter]` is predictable nil. Hence `fullrow` is nil, hence an error. What you’ve seen in console is the printed value from the previous loop. BTW, the whole code looks too phpyish. `items.each` is more suitable here.

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an off by one error, you are reading past the end of the items array. If there are 10 lines in the CSV file, the lines will be an array with indexes from 0 to 9, not 1 to 10.

Change your while to look like this

```
counter = 0
while counter < linesAmount
  ...
end
```

However a better approach overall would be to just do the following

```
CSV.readlines('somefile.csv').each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: condition `counter <= linesAmount` will run for 0..10, still raising an exception.

Comment: You are right, you arrived at exactly the wrong time, I think it was like that for about 20 seconds before I edited to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

`CSV.read` and `CSV.readlines` return arrays. If your array contains two values, then `size` returns `2`. But the indexes you need to call are `items[0]` and items[1]. Therefore this line

```
items[counter]
```

throws an error.

Change the line to

```
items[counter - 1]
```

and it should work.

Furthermore you can improve your code by using Ruby idioms:

```
begin
 items = CSV.read('somefile.csv')
 items.each do |item|
   puts item[0]
 end
end
```